# Inheritance and dependencies modeling in UML

Tags: uml

I'm trying to model class relationships in Cairngorm micro-architecture for Flex RIA applications. I have a little confusion.

For example, I have two classes FrontController and Controller. Controller extends FrontController.
On the other side, I have ICommand interface and SaveEmployeeCommand which implements ICommand.

FrontController has this two methods...

```
  public function addCommand( commandName : String, commandRef : Class, useWeakReference : Boolean = true ) : void
  {
     if( commands[ commandName ] != null )
        throw new CairngormError( CairngormMessageCodes.COMMAND_ALREADY_REGISTERED, commandName );

     commands[ commandName ] = commandRef;
     CairngormEventDispatcher.getInstance().addEventListener( commandName, executeCommand, false, 0, useWeakReference );
  }

 /**
  * Executes the command
  */  
  protected function executeCommand( event : CairngormEvent ) : void
  {
     var commandToInitialise : Class = getCommand( event.type );
     //#### THIS IS DEPENDENCY ON ICommand INTERFACE ####
     var commandToExecute : ICommand = new commandToInitialise();

     commandToExecute.execute( event );
  }
```

Controller has init method in constructor wich is like this...

```
public function init():void
{
    // SaveEmployeeEvent extends CairngormEvent
    // SaveEmployeeCommand implements ICommand interface
    //### THIS IS DEPENDENCY ON SaveEmployeeEvent AND SaveEmployeeCommand ###
    addCommand(SaveEmployeeEvent.SAVE, SaveEmployeeCommand);
}
```

So, let's consider just dependencies on commands. If we look at code we will see that FrontController has dependency on ICommand and that Controller has some kind of dependency on SaveEmployeeCommand.**Should I show both 'Controllers->Commands' dependencies on UML class diagram?**(First dependency is FrontController->ICommand, second is Controller->SaveEmployeeCommand)
My confusion is about inheritance part. If I put inheritance relationship between FrontController and Controller, it means that Controller is also FrontController, so he has dependency on ICommand too(dependency is inherited with addCommand method). How should I model this situation? I put some example of possible solution... Any suggests?

[image: Dependencies model]

Answer (score 0):

The relations in your diagram look correct, except for the stereotype. I would change dependency between FrontController and ICommand to `<<Instantiate>>`.